# Cypher - How to call a procedure multiple times in loop?

Tags: loops, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In Neo4j Browser, I tried to call a procedure multiple times in a loop, but Neo4j reported the same error: **Query cannot conclude with CALL (must be RETURN or an update clause)**. Specifically,

- With `UNWIND` ([documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/)):

```
UNWIND [10, 20] AS age_num
MATCH (n:User {name: 'a', age: age_num})
CALL apoc.nodes.delete(n)
```

...got `Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError`:

```
Query cannot conclude with CALL (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 3, column 1 (offset: 68))
"CALL apoc.nodes.delete(n)"
 ^
```

- With `apoc.periodic.iterate()` ([documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/periodic-execution/)):

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "UNWIND [10, 20] AS age_num MATCH (n:User {name: 'a', age: age_num}) RETURN n",
    "CALL apoc.nodes.delete(n)",
    {batchMode: 'SINGLE', parallel: false}
)
```

...got `errorMessages`:

```
{
  "Query cannot conclude with CALL (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 1, column 15 (offset: 14))\r\n\" WITH $n AS n CALL apoc.nodes.delete(n)\"\r\n               ^": 1
}
```

The procedure `apoc.nodes.delete()` here is just an example. Please don't advise me on using `DETACH DELETE` instead.

**Question**: In Cypher, how is it supposed to call a procedure multiple times in a loop, each time might have a different parameter, e.g. a different property value?

Environment: Neo4j Desktop v4.0.4, Windows 8.1 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a `RETURN` statement at the end of the query like the error states. Basically, if you only call a single procedure, then cypher won't bug you with this. But if you do any kind of `MATCH` before a procedure call, you have to end the query with `RETURN`. You could also just use `DETACH DELETE` cypher statement instead.

Version with DETACH DELETE:

```
UNWIND [10, 20] AS age_num
MATCH (n:User {name: 'a', age: age_num})
DETACH DELETE n
```

Version with APOC:

```
UNWIND [10, 20] AS age_num
MATCH (n:User {name: 'a', age: age_num})
CALL apoc.nodes.delete(n) YIELD value
RETURN distinct 'done'
```

Edit: I have fixed the output as per the OP comment

Comment: I ran the code snippet (APOC version), got the error `Unknown procedure output`. Checked with `CALL apoc.help('apoc.nodes.delete')`, and found the returned result should be named `value`. Fixed it, then the code ran well. Thank you.